# How to create a node js application with vue js as frontend and postgres as backend

Tags: node.js, vue.js, oauth-2.0

I would like to know the `folder structure` of `NodeJs` as server side `VueJs` and  `postgres` as back end

As my requirement is we will register user (not from external site ) we will create the user

After authentication authorized user can use web service or content 
most important `user authentication`. which authentication method  should use

I have read about passport it is using for authentication between various external site 
I have read number of topics i could not found suitable, please guide me

```
summaries the requirement
```

1. **folder structure of node**
2. **user authentication**
3. **NodeJs and VueJs connection**
4. **open source**